# WebQuiz Package on LaTeX

Tags: online, questionnaire, webquiz

I am a teacher and am trying to create math assignments online for my students using LaTeX.

- I am using [WebQuiz](https://ctan.org/pkg/webquiz) (see "online manual") in order to do this.
  I clicked the "download" button at the bottom of that link and have that zip file on my desktop. In that folder, I clicked on "scripts" and then clicked on "webquiz." This gives the following message in gray below.

I have noted there is a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480668/compile-webquiz) in case this helps.

When I initialize WebQuiz I get the following message...

```
If you want to continue then WebQuiz will guide you through the
initialisation process.  For more information about the steps involved
see Section 3.2 of the WebQuiz manual On many systems, you can open
the webquiz manual using the command: texdoc webquiz

Press RETURN to continue...
----
To make files accessible from your web server WebQuiz needs:
  o A directory, or folder, on your server that is visible from your
    web server. This directory MUST be accessible from the web. It can
    either be a "system" directory or in your personal web directories.
  o The relative URL for accessing these files from the web. This is
    the part of the URL that you have to add to your "root" URL to
    access the files. For example, if the URL for your department is
        http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/
    and the WebQuiz files can be accessed as
        http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/teaching/WebQuiz
    then the relative URL for the WebQuiz files is /teaching/WebQuiz

It is recommended that you create a separate directory for WebQuiz on your
web server. The location of the files on your web server will depend on
your operating system and system configuration. A common sysem location
for the WebQuiz web directory on a Windows system is
     c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebQuiz

Press RETURN to continue...
```

> I am confused when I get to this point how to make a web directory because isn't "WebQuiz" the folder that is the zip folder? Am I suppose to make folders where the "WebQuiz" folder is inside the "wwwroot" folder which is inside the folder "inetpub"? It just seems strange to do that. I have tried using the package webquiz and creating another document. I am not sure what to do from here to get this up and running. So, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I know a lot of math teachers that are frustrated with creating online quizzes right now. This "WebQuiz" thing seems really cool and will help me out a lot! Please help! I want it!!!

Comment: Did you store your zip on a web server? If you haven't got a private web server this will hardly work as far as I understand. If you have one webserver you shoud unpack the zip and point at its location. Btw, the `python` flag is not best suited to your question, which is not related to python.

Comment: @sztruks How do you store the zip on a web server? I am having difficulties getting the quizzes online. I don't know how to access them or where to go for a URL. I have the quizzes working in the way that I can see them as a PDF. I have installed "TeX Live" and then ran the file "install-tl-windows" as an administrator. I am not sure what to do from here...

Comment: I got to the part where I am trying to process the quiz online using the webquiz command. I read the following but I am not sure how to do this. Maybe this is what you were talking about with the web server. "Of course, the real reason for using WebQuiz is to create a web page for the quiz, which you do
by processing the quiz using the webquiz command )instead of, say pdflatex)."

Comment: A web server is a file arborescence as any other. When you have the owner rights on a web server, you can modify the files, unzip an archive and so on… Just like on your personal computer, with the difference that very often you make this operations on a remote host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the package to work it is necessary to put some CSS style files and some javascript files somewhere in your web directories so that they are accessible to the quiz pages from your web server. By default the webquiz files are in the TeX directories, which are not accessible from your web server. The initialisation script is asking where it can install these files so that they accessible from the web.